# Saving image from "pictureBox1" to a file with a click on a button in C#

Tags: c#

I found this code on here, and I want to save the image I get in my "pictureBox1" with a button like under, how can I implement these together?
I have the picture showing in the pictureBox1, I want to click a button and be able to store the picture on my PC.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This is the code to save image:

```
public static void SaveImageCapture(System.Drawing.Image image)

SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
s.FileName = "Image";// Default file name
s.DefaultExt = ".Jpg";// Default file extension
s.Filter = "Image (.jpg)|*.jpg"; // Filter files by extension

s.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

s.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (s.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Save Image
    string filename = s.FileName;

  (System.IO.FileStream fstream = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
        image.Save(fstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        fstream.Close();
```

Comment: `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){SaveImageCapture(pictureBox1.Image);}` ??

Comment: code is not completed. you need `using`statement. what do you mean by implement these together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also not 100% sure i understand what you mean. but here is a 2 lines of codes, showing the simplest way of loading and saving an image into a picturebox.

```
// 1. Load a picture into the picturebox
PictureBox pic = new PictureBox() { Image = Image.FromFile("SomeFile.jpg") };

// 2. Save it to a file again
pic.Image.Save("SomeFilePath.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: I have the picture showing in the pictureBox1, I want to click a button and be able to store the picture on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"C:\Temp\test.jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

   }
```